# Embeding GeoNetwork's client in my application

Tags: geonetwork

Does anybody knows how to embed my GeoNetwork client in my application so that user will be able to publish their metadata while they are still on the application.

Comment: What language is your client in? What have you already done? Might it make more sense to use the widgets (http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.3/eng/widgets/index.html)? Or perhaps the XML services (http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/developer/xml_services/index.html)? Hard to say without any details, so perhaps you could update your question to allow us to help you?

Comment: my application is web application which uses java script, Java script API's like Open layers and GeoExt and HTMl, CSS. i'm also using python on the server side. my idea is to enable users to publish their metadata about the feature they are going to upload to my database.

Comment: Then definitely use the xml services as @BradHards suggests.

Comment: for some reason i made a decision to use client side scripting GeoExt (leaving out python) to develop the application. i want to integrate search  and display search result functionality of geonetwork to search wms metadata harvested and stored in geonetwork. i read the API but it lucks good examples. please if you know some working example.